# What is the number of possible simple directed graphs of $n$ elements without 2-cycles and self-loops?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, network, adjacency-matrix

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a graph with $n$ vertices. Let $a_{ij}$ denote the entry in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column.

For a given $n$, how can we compute the number of possible networks, $f(n)$, such that

1. There are no self-loops: $a_{ii}=0$
2. There are no 2-cycles: $a_{ij}=1\implies a_{ji}=0$
3. there is at most one edge between two vertices: $a_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$

To get some intuition, I wrote a script that generates all such networks for $n=3,4,5$ and got $27,729,59049$ possible networks respectively. I did some reverse engineering and got that
$$f(n)=3^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

However, I don't understand why is this the case. It is possible, of course, that the function I deduced is wrong and that it only works for those three integers.

Can someone shed some light on whether this formula is correct and why is this the case?

Comment: Do you allow multiple edges between two vertices?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel right, I forgot to clarify, I will edit the question. Thank you for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all vertices are labelled, for each of the $\binom n2=\frac{n(n-1)}2$ pairs of vertices there are three possibilities: there is an edge from $A$ to $B$, there is an edge from $B$ to $A$, there is no edge between $A$ and $B$. There are no other restrictions, so the number of different graphs is $3^{n(n-1)/2}$.